# Angular Material - conditionally disable animations

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using **Angular 6** including **Angular Material 6.0.1** in my application.
I am using an `Tab layout` as a parent which could have a `Collapsible` as a child.

I am trying to **disable the animation in the parent tab** using the **`@disabled property`** but then it also disables the animation of the collapsible.

Is there a workaround to get over this?

Answer (score 0):

Despite inner animations being disabled, a parent animation can query() for inner elements located in disabled areas of the template and still animate them if needed. This is also the case for when a sub animation is queried by a parent and then later animated using animateChild().

```
animations: [
trigger('queryAnimation', [
transition('* => goAnimate', [
query('h1', style({ opacity: 0 })),
query('h1', animate(1000, style({ opacity: 1 })),
query('.content', animate(1000, style({ opacity: 1 }))
])
 ])
]
```